# Eclipse Crashing on Startup

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Whenever I try to start eclipse, the Loading Screen comes up for about a second, and suddenly disappears. No errors come up. I tried running it from command prompt, and the same thing happened, with no errors. Then, I tried doing ".../eclipse/eclipse.exe -clean" and it didn't do anything.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did u check JAVA home path if it is set correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is happening because of information written**eclipse.ini** inside your extracted eclipse folder

original data in eclipse.ini is

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

change it size of Xmx512 to 1024 below is information

If you get the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space while running Java applications, it means that your Java application environment don’t have the sufficient space to store the values needed for your application. This could be because of the following reasons:
By mistake, you have set the less memory for your Java environment (or)
Your epplication is huge and allocated memory is not enough for your application’s size
In the either case, increasing the size of the memory is the solution. You can update the VM arguments as below to fix this issue. You have to select the application and update the required value as -Xms512M -Xmx1024M. This would resolve the problem while that application is running.

also **delete .metadata file of your workspace and your problem will get solve**

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete .snap file in workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources folder.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! The .snap file is there due to previous Eclipse crash. For some reason the IDE fails to read/reconcile the snapshot and exits. Looks like a bug in Eclipse (2019 RCP dev package). Deleting the .snap file preserves the workspace content, while deleting the .metadata will force you to re-import your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because of low memory problem on Eclipse launcher. Try to increase the **PermGen** memory size in `eclipse.ini` file inside Eclipse folder. You have to extend the memory size in
 `--launcher.XXMaxPermSize` to `1024M` and `-Xms512m`  `-Xmx1024m`