# Eclipse Crashing on Startup with No Errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am currently using Eclipse Luna on Windows 8.1 on a 64 bit system.
I have recently been trying to learn Android development on Eclipse. For the past two weeks or so everything has been functioning fine and Eclipse (as well as the Android SDKs) were installed properly and working. Today however, whenever I tried to start Eclipse the loading screen would pop up for a few seconds, the program would then stop responding and close shortly after that.

This was especially confusing because no error messages would pop up and I have no idea what's wrong. I have already tried to delete some of the .snap files found in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources but could not find any. And as per this topic

[Eclipse Crashing on Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399893/eclipse-crashing-on-startup)

Tried to increase the memory but neither of these things have helped. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could give me some advice on how to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting .eclipse and .android folders in users folder also sdk folder then unpack eclipse folder on other local disk and link it to new sdk folder. That can help.

Eclipse have so many crashes lately, in the future i would suggest you to switch to **android studio** there is stable version month ago released.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I've tried your recommendations, but unfortunately Eclipse is still not starting. Thank you very much for your help though, and I probably will be switching to Android Studio soon.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve this issue by uninstalling and re-installing Java. I have no idea why this worked but it seems to have solved the problem.